# Error inserting data to sql table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'am working on Oracle database. After creating tables correctly, I have tried to insert data to my tables but I get this error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`.
Here is my [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e84886/5).

I guess the problem here:

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE (NCMD, DATECMD) VALUES ('C001', '10/12/2003');
INSERT INTO COMMANDE (NCMD, NCL) VALUES ('C002', 'CL05');
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES ('C003', '15/01/2004', 'CL03');
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES ('C004', '03/09/2003', 'CL10');
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES ('C005', '11/03/2004', 'CL03');
```

What does this error mean? And how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: insert statements should be in schema pane http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9271

Comment: @Lashane answer edited, I am getting another error!!

Comment: what answer edited? if you're getting another error - post another question

Comment: If you are getting a different error, please update your post with the correct error.  It sounds like perhaps you have not researched this well enough.

Comment: The data column is in the commande table , but there is no insert statement relating to it, please post it, and the error

Comment: I get `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` when I build the schema, then run, not `ORA-01843: not a valid month`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

It seems that there is something wrong with date format in my sql request.

Changing this:

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE (NCMD, DATECMD) VALUES ('C001', '10/12/2003');
```

To this

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE (NCMD, DATECMD) VALUES ('C001', TO_DATE ('10/12/2003', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

solved my problem.